# public DNS of ec2 not opening in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

Public DNS of my ec2 instance is not opening in browser.
the public DNS created via beanstalk are opening. why is that ? how to resolve?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question does not have much detail, so it is difficult to provide an answer. Could you please Edit your question and provide more information, such as exactly what you are trying to do and how you have configured your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot an elastic beanstalk deployment, start with the following:

1. Check your AWS EB logs, did your app launch succesfully?
2. What port is your application running on; port 8080, 9000, 80, ... ?
3. Is the security group of the EC2 instance it's running on, opened for the port where your application is running?
4. Does your AWS EB application need any specific IAM permissions to access resources e.g. an RDS database, a Lambda function?

Comment: yeah it was tcp port 80 issue. fixed it thnkx